# Rise of the Separatists sourcebook talent clarification

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

In the *Fantasy Flight Games* Star Wars RPG, in the sourcebook *Rise of the Separatists*, the talent called "Consider Our Options" states:

> The character may take the Consider Our Options action, making a Hard Negotiation check. If the check succeeds, until the start of the character's next turn, any enemy that attacks the character suffers 2 strain, plus 1 strain per additional 2 successes on the character's check, before resolving the attack. (If this strain causes an adversary to become incapacitated, the GM may determine that adversary simply bows out of the fight.) The effect ends if the character inflicts damage on an enemy.

In the case that a Minion or Rival, as opposed to a Nemesis,  attacks the character, taking strain as damage per the rules of Minions and Rivals, count as inflicting damage and thus ending the effect according to "The effect ends if the character inflicts damage on an enemy." which is stated at the end of the talent?

If it might help clarify, the "Improved" version of the talent states:

> When the character takes the Consider Our Options action, the character may choose to have the effects also apply to attacks that target the character's allies who are within short range. The effect ends for all characters if the character or an affected ally inflict damage on an enemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reading of

> 'any enemy that attacks the character suffers 2 strain, plus 1 strain per additional 2 successes on the character's check'

Is that it is strain inflicted by that minion on itself, and is thus not damage inflicted by the character. It could have chosen to attack someone else, or do something else entirely - just as a PC generally inflicts voluntary strain on themselves when they take a second maneuver. The strain suffered for taking a second maneuver does not trigger talents such as Resolve, which reduces the cost of involuntarily suffered strain; in this case the minion is voluntarily suffering the strain (or wounds) in order to attack you.

This interpretation is easily woven into the flavour of the talent; The PC has put doubt into the Minion's mind, and while it could push through that doubt it will have to strain (or rather wound) itself to do so.